# how to begin with single user chat in IOS?

Tags: ios, chat

I am new to IOS and I want to create an app with single user chat feature. I don't have any idea that how should I start with chat feature. I searched for it and found QUICKBLOX sdk but the problem is that this sdk shows its image in application. can anybody tell me that which api or sdk should I user or how should I start from the beginning to create a basic chat app?

Comment: first of all, you need a bigger webservice to start up with individual chat application. XMMP server can be used to chat even with a facebook user with out any webservices!

Answer (score 2):

You need a XMPP server to pass the chat messages to different devices.
If you want to build the server on your own, check [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/). 
If you want to sexy node.js implementation ,check [xmppjs]
(https://github.com/mwild1/xmppjs). 
If you want to use third-party services, [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/) is certainly a way to go.

There are other service providers:

- [Parse](http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com): Parse SDK is easy to use, but it doesn't support real-time messaging. You have to check new messages from time to time.
- [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html): it provides real-time messaging support, but you have to pay $45/month for 200 active connections.
- [Layer](https://layer.com/docs/ios#messages): same as firebase, but it has an easy-to-use SDK. Still in alpha.

If you don't want to mess with XMPP, [socket.io](http://socket.io) (for nodejs lovers) and [signalr](http://signalr.net/) (for ASP.NET lovers) are alternative solutions.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.